# Memcached and Tomcat 8 incompatibility

Tags: tomcat, grails, memcached, tomcat8

I'm trying to deploy a Grails application into a Tomcat 8.0.15. In case it matters, the OS is CentOS 7, Java version is 1.7.0_71 and memcached version is 1.4.20.

I use the [Grails Standalone Tomcat plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/standalone-tomcat-memcached) to use memcached as the session manager and it worked great with Tomcat 7. Unfortunately, migrating to Tomcat 8 was not as simple as expected.

I found this among its dependencies: `de.javakaffee.msm:memcached-session-manager-tc7:1.6.4` and so I tried changing it to `tc8` (which exists in [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.javakaffee.msm/memcached-session-manager-tc8/1.8.3)) and updating the versions of various other plugins.

Unfortunately, I came across a problem while deploying the application on Tomcat 8:

```
04-Feb-2015 16:26:08.371 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-17] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
2015-02-04 16:26:18 ERROR [GrailsContextLoaderListener] Error initializing the application: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager.changeSessionId(Lorg/apache/catalina/Session;)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, de/javakaffee/web/msm/MemcachedBackupSessionManager, and its superclass loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type ger.changeSessionId(Lorg/apache/catalina/Session;)V used in the signature
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager.changeSessionId(Lorg/apache/catalina/Session;)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, de/javakaffee/web/msm/MemcachedBackupSessionManager, and its superclass loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type ger.changeSessionId(Lorg/apache/catalina/Session;)V used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In summary, there is a method called `changeSessionId` which is overriden by the class `de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager` but it has something different than what the class loader was expecting.

I found no help on Google and tried changing lots of versions and dependencies to no avail, so I decided to rollback to Tomcat 7. But I wanted to leave this here in case someone finds the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Grails plugin uses tomcat7 jar of memcached-session-manager

https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-standalone-tomcat-memcached/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L25

As per the documentation of Memcache session manager each tomcat 6, 7 & 8 have their own jar https://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration

Comment: Yes, I know. I stated in the question that I tried changing the dependency of the plugin to Tomcat8's jar, but it didn't work :(